# SQL SELECT Function In Wordpress Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, select

I'm working on a basic selection function that grabs the row with the lowest id. Then just to make sure it works I have it dump the array, but something is wrong and it keeps returning null. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```
function select_min_id(){
    global $wpdb;

    $table = 'my_table';

    $query = '"SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE id=(select min(id) from '.$table.')"';

    $row = $wpdb->get_row($query, ARRAY_A);

    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Wordpress but try `SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id LIMIT 1`

Comment: No luck, i tried `$query = '"SELECT * FROM '.$table.' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1"';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide the error you get?

And I was curious about why you use single quotes and double quotes on your query? You could simply write

`$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=(select min(id) FROM $table)";`

If you didn't know, when you are using double quotes, you can put PHP variables in a string without breaking it.